# What happened to ifstream _Read_s?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, stl

I am porting a Visual Studio solution from version 2005 to version 2010.

One of the project is a native C++ project that makes use of ifstream.

The conversion process completed succsesfully, however when I try to build the native project the compiler says that "_Read_s is not a member of ifstream".

What happened to _Read_s?

There were compiler changes that make somehow the method not accesible?

This is the code that visual studio 2005 correctly builds:

```
ifstream binfile(pathFileToRead, ios::in | ios::binary | ios::beg);

while (!binfile.eof())
{
    binfile._Read_s(fileBuffer, CACHE_SIZE, CACHE_SIZE);

    //Do something with fileBuffer
}
```

Comment: What is `_Read_s`? I've never seen that. What is the code that generates the error?

Comment: As I understand _Read_s is a sort of safer version of Read that microsoft added to its STL implementation... I'll add a code example

Comment: As an aside, `while (!eof())` is nearly always a bug in C/C++.

Comment: Pisses me off when MS can't even be bothered to explain why this function exists and how it differs from the standard ones. Oh, and, that it's not standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the non-standard `basic_istream::_Read_s()` only existed in VS 2005 and VS 2008.

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985905.aspx

You should probably just change it to use the standard `basic_istream::read()` function:

```
binfile.read(fileBuffer, CACHE_SIZE);
```

Comment: Thanks also for the hint on eof. Safer implementation looked as a good idea but it didn't stood many version ;-).

Comment: This particular safer function seemed to offer little safety over the standard function.  I assume that's one factor in removing it.

Comment: [basic_istream::_Read_s is undefined | Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedbackdetail/view/533292/basic-istream-read-s-is-undefined)